# Code generator has deoptimised the styling in react-native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, babeljs

I am getting this after my react native build is successful :

> transform[stderr]: [BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised
> the styling of /Users/myName/Desktop/mool_mobile/unknown as it exceeds
> the max of 500KB.

In the emulator the splash screen shows up for 1 minute or so and then it eventually crashes. Couldn't find much resources regarding this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As it says in this Response:

**It's just a warning (not an error) that can be safely ignored.**

However, if you want to silence it, you might try to set the https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#compact option to `true`

Response link: https://github.com/babel/babel/discussions/13676#discussioncomment-1183149